# How to access an unknown property in C# Generics

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I am creating a general repository class as part of my Entity Framework Code First data layer. To get the single row by id, if all the entities have id name as "ID" it will work as shown by the following:

```
public T GetSingle(int id)
    {
        return GetAll().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);
    }
```

But I would like to name my entity primarykey as "EnityName"+Id, such as AddressId or ApplicantId etc. Is there any way to have the code:

```
return GetAll().FirstOrDefault(x => x.<EntityName>Id == id);
```

to make to work?

Thanks

Comment: Please, have a look at `ExpandoObject`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I don't think it's possible, having a property with the same name in all your entities (enforced by an interface) is definitely the way to go. Is there any reason why you want to have your property named `EntityNameId`? Note that the name of the property can be different from the name of the column in the database (using the `Column("nameOfTheColumn")` attribute)

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the clarification. I will take the route you have suggested and  use data annotation to name the columns.

Comment: Hmm, I suppose that you could annotate each Code First model in some way to denote the name (which could be found using reflection), but wouldn't it be simpler to just use the "ID" property?

Comment: I think you can use the uniqueidentifier in tsql to find the name of the column and it's value as demoed in this blog: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/06/18/sql-server-identifying-column-data-type-of-uniqueidentifier-without-querying-system-tables/     . What I think would complicate this is if the repository is dealing with generics, the id column in different table can have different types of identity values returned. (i.e., string, int, guid, etc., ...). You'll probably need to convert the tsql instructions to linq. Also, you will need a way of telling the id type afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easier only create method "Get single" and pass predicate

```
   public virtual T GetSingle(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        if (predicate != null)
        {
            return context.Set<T>().Where(predicate).SingleOrDefault();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Predicate value is null");
        }
    }
```

And call it:

```
yourContext.GetSingle(g => g.Id == id);
```

Answer (score -3):

you can use Attributes for this and read the Property which has the right Attribute.

```
public abstract class MyIdAttribute: Attribute
{
}

public class MyClass
{
    [MyId]
    WhatEverName {get; set;}
}
```

and in your Method

```
public T GetSingle(int id)
{
    var propertyInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(property => property.GetCustomAttributes<MyIdAttribute>().Count() > 0).ToList();
    if (propertyInfos.Any())
    {
        foreach(T current in GetAll())
        {
            object value = propertyInfos[0].GetValue(current);
            if(value == id)
            {
                return current;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Cheers

Thomas